Why is $\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$?
I saw the definition of the sign function in the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function.
The definition made me wondering why at $\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$.
Note:$$\operatorname{sign}(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}=\frac{x}{|x|}$$
If we set $x=0$, then:
$$\operatorname{sign}(0)=\frac0{0}=\text{indeterminate}$$
I want to know why at $x=0$, $\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$.
I have a feeling that this has some connection with physics, but I don't have any examples or proof on this.
Mathematical question: What property of $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ is preserved if and only if $\operatorname{sign}(0)= 0$.

We want the signum of a positive number to be 1 and the signum of a negative number to be -1.   What should we do with zero? We can either leave the signum of 0 undefined or make some kind of sensible convention.  Defining the signum of 0 to be 0 seems reasonable.

It's nice to have some definition at zero so that the sign function is the weak derivative of the absolute value. It's nice to have it zero at zero so that you get the average of the left and right hand limits and pointwise convergence in the Fourier series. There is a case for just leaving it undefined, but if you are going to define it, there isn't really a natural other choice.

This is a good question. I tried to get it to re-open. The answer is "because we want $\operatorname{sign}(xy)= \operatorname{sign}(x)\operatorname{sign}(y)$".

(1) Whether or not this is a good question, this isn't the right site for it---this is a question about mathematics, not math education. (2) When you say "we want" this function to have certain properties, who is this "we"? Can you provide a citation?

@XanderHenderson asking for a citation on this site in that context is one of the most uncharitable and condescending things you can do. Fair enough there's a question as to whether it should be on mathemematics or matheducators, I charitably took the question as asking about how to teach why sign(0) = 0. Did anyone tell the original poster to just ask this on Mathematics?
Anyway, when I say "we want" it's just common short-hand for "this is a key property so if you want to not break this property then you need sign(0) = 0".

I felt like this question (my post) belongs to this website than math.exchange, because I want to focus more on the motivation why we define sgn(0)=0.
We = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function".
Note: I use "we", because I felt like this is the most accepted definition, although I don't have proof of this, if this is really the most accepted definition and why.

If this question is of interest to you then the Talk page associated with the Wikipedia article is relevant. Based on what I read there, I doubt that you are going to find agreement about the "correct" convention, even in the mathematics literature, and for most things it's not going to matter very much. Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article itself is poorly referenced, with half the references to other online encyclopedias. A question about motivation or presentation is not an education question unless there's a pedagogical issue at stake.

@cheyne This is a nice property, the desire for which could certainly motivate the choice of $\textrm{sign}(0) = 0$.  I think that a question which could be suitable for this site would ask about how to motivate seemingly arbitrary choices in definitions more generally.  I do agree that a nice strategy is to showcase some nice property which we desire to hold, whose only obstruction is the resolution of the edge case in a particular way.  I wonder if there are any elementary examples of two conflicting nice properties leading to two conflicting "natural" definitions?
